# Rails active record associations referring to same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for some assistance with setting up activerecord associations between these two tables.

In particular the associations with Government party Id and Opposition Party id - which I would like to both point back to the parties table.

Can someone please assist with how I would set them up in my models?

```
Tables

Election
Id:integer
Location_id:integer
Date:date
Government_party_id:integer
Government_seats:integer
Government_tpp:float
Opposition_party_id:integer
Opposition_seats:integer
opposition_tpp:float
Total_seats:integer

Party
Id:integer
Name:string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Election < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :government_party, class_name: 'Party', foreign_key: 'Government_party_id'
  belongs_to :opposition_party, class_name: 'Party', foreign_key: 'Opposition_party_id'
end
```

Comment: Should normally use lowercase for foreign keys (government_party_id)

Comment: @mahemoff Oh, even if the DB column is in a different case?

Comment: No, should match the DB. I guess the way it's written, the question hints that they do begin with uppercase, so I get why you wrote it that way. It's just fairly unusual in any context to have a dashed name starting with uppercase.

Comment: Thanks for this. What would I have in my Party model class?

Comment: you can use `has_many` or `has_one` based on the number of elections per party